# spring mvc simpleformcontroller - how to stop execution when exception thrown

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using simpleformcontroller and get exception thrown in my OnSubmit method. This does not seem to stop the simpleformcontroler process as it redisplays my form.

I can see from log4j output that the exception is getting caught and forwarding to my error page as expected. I can also tell the onSubmit method does not continue after the exception. Which is all good.

But i do not see the error page as the simpleformcontroller starts up again and goes through processing for a new form (i can see in log4j ouput Spring log statements 'Displaying New form', 'Creating new command of class ..'. The normal form page is then displayed again.

So the problem is that the exception does not seem to terminate the SimpleFormController, it carries on to display the form again.

Anyone help?
Thanks Alan

Comment: what do the logs say after forwarding to the error page?

Comment: SimpleFormController etc are deprecated... consider moving to the annotation-based approach. Download the latest petclinic to see how that works

Comment: This is an existing application on old versions of java so i cant easily go to the annotated approach - unfortunately.

Comment: Immediately after the last log message from the error handling servlet - i get logging from my SFC saying 'Displaying new form'. Im going to reduce my SFC to the bare minimum and throw an exception in onSubmit and see if that helps me track it down. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Turned out this was not spring behaviour, but was problem caused by the existing application error page when an exception is thrown on a page in a frameset.